# How to stop while loop when key pressed

Tags: python

I'm making a stopwatch program. This is the current code:

```
import keyboard
from time import sleep

i = 0

while not keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
    i += 1
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
print('ended')
```

The problem with this code is you have to click s after 1 second, 2 seconds, etc. I want it to stop at any time you click s, not if you click s every 1 second. Can someone help me do this?

Comment: Sleep shorter, but only print the time each time the time changes, or you can use the `on_key_press` event that supports a callback that you could use to change the current state: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press_key

Comment: @MatsLindh What?

Comment: Are you running this on linux or windows or some other OS?  Do you want a cross platfom solution?

Comment: @cup windows, sure